# Linux Mint 'rvm requirements' failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, installation, linux-mint

I run Linux Mint 16 (petra) and have increasingly encountered issues where it says it needs a package, it even tells me what it needs me to install, I try to install exactly that package, and then it says "hey that package doesnt exist! haha!"

It is becoming incredibly frustrating and unfortunately I'm totally out of luck when it comes to reinstalling the OS because I need an ethernet cable and a router both of which I do not have. I have tried to start learning Erlang which has become impossible because I can't even get it installed (see my previous stackoverflow post) and now I can't even get rails working, which is something I was working on very regularly prior to starting an internship this summer.

Here is my issue.

> core@core ~ $ rvm requirements
>
> Checking requirements for mint.
>   Installing requirements for mint. 
>   Updating system..core password
>   required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update':  ...............
>   Installing required packages: libreadline6-dev, libyaml-dev, autoconf,
>   libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, automake, libtool, libffi-dev..... Error
>   running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev
>   autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool libffi-dev',
>   showing last 15 lines of
>   /home/core/.rvm/log/1404864015/package_install_libreadline6-dev_libyaml-dev_autoconf_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_automake_libtool_libffi-dev.log
>   is only available from another source
>
> Package libtool is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Unable to locate package libreadline6-dev E: Package 'autoconf' has
>   no installation candidate E: Unable to locate package libgdbm-dev E:
>   Unable to locate package libncurses5-dev E: Package 'automake' has no
>   installation candidate E: Package 'libtool' has no installation
>   candidate E: Unable to locate package libffi-dev
>   + return 100
>   + return 100 Requirements installation failed with status: 100.

I tried to install several of those packages, and then I get the message "hey that package doesn't exist!"

What can I do?

Please help me resolve this so I can become productive again. Very very much appreciated in advance!

UPDATE: iain suggested that I run a command which I did and it produced this:

> core@core ~ $ sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential
>   libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
>   [sudo] password for core:  Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Package
>   autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package. This
>   may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only
>   available from another source
>
> E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate E: Unable to
>   locate package libreadline6-dev

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get update` first?

Comment: Yes, everything is completely up to date.

Comment: I've added a list of packages below, but maybe it will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the packages I install to get Ruby to build on an Ubuntu system

```
make
autoconf
libtool
build-essential
libffi-dev
libgdbm-dev
libncurses5-dev
libreadline-dev
libssl-dev
libyaml-dev
zlib1g-dev
```

I got most of that list from [the ruby-build wiki](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki#suggested-build-environment), which suggests:

```
apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

but I add in `make` too, for good measure.

---

I got this from an Ubuntu box provided by Vagrant, the [hashicorp/precise64](https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise64) which should (hopefully) be close enough to what Mint is using to check against.

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ precise main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120424.1)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

The MD5 may help:

```
$ md5 sources.list 
MD5 (sources.list) = b966730006afc9e02e6d56d7ceb96af5
```

Comment: @ArthurCollé the only other thing I can think of is to run `apt-get check` (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto for more commands) and/or to check the repository lists are ok and reachable.

Comment: @ArthurCollé (From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) you could check `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but you should probably check it against a known-good list… I'll try and find one.

Comment: Thanks again for this, appreciate it! [6 years later...]

Comment: @ArthurCollé Better late than never :)